# Setting default project view extent in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgs, mapcanvas, default

I'm trying to find a setting in QGIS that will allow me to save a default view extent - so that when I open a saved project file, it opens on the area of interest.

Currently the map loads at some other random point thousands of kilometers away (not even related to the project CRS).

This means that I either have to right-click and 'zoom to layer' or use 'spatial bookmarks' but it's a bit annoying, so I'm thinking there must be some way to define what appears in the map canvas window / what map extent is show on load up.

It's implied in this help file (https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/project_files.html) ...that this should happen by default ("Last viewed extent") ..but it doesn't do it.

Comment: You could create a project template?

Comment: Can you please elaborate - how do you do that and how exactly does that solve the problem?

Comment: Set up the map canvas to the CRS and extent you need, the save it a template using `project - save as`.

Comment: ..and I would need to do this for every save file, work project or location? Does it need to be loaded every time?

Comment: Since I have no idea, how you're working, I can't answer that.

Comment: ...but some knowledge of your proposed solution would facilitate answering it. What does a project template do? How does it work? How does it solve my problem exactly?

Comment: I don't know, whether it solves your problem or not, which is why I posted it as a comment with a questionmark at the end. I suggest you try and decide, whether this solves your problem.

Comment: So if you don't know anything about the technique or how it might be relevant, then why are you proposing it?

Comment: Because it could be a possible solution to what you ask, as far as I understand the technique, as well as what you're asking. How about you have a look at it and then state, whether it is suitable, or not, and also specify what it lacks.

Comment: It should return the last viewed extent by default.  What happens if you create and save a test project?  If that works  I would probably copy and paste the layers of your current malfunctioning project into a new project, save it and see if that works.  If it doesn't I'd run a geometry check on the layers.  I'd also check your CRS.

Comment: Thanks Johns, it's never done that for me. I wasn't sure if QGIS was supposed to or not, so that's an interesting point. I tried your suggestion and no. Whether I have a default CRS set or not, it doesn't remember the view extent. Do you know if there is  a setting for this?